# Ormlite: foreignAutoCreate insert if not exists

Tags: java, android, ormlite

i noticed that foreignAutoCreate crash when a related data already exists, throwing something like this:

```
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (2067) abort at 20 in [INSERT INTO `Group` (... etc,`id` ) VALUES (?,?,?)]:
    UNIQUE constraint failed: Group.id
```

but i have a list, example:

```
List<User> lstUsers = //values
```

im inserting values with a loop "for" with createOrUpdate:

```
for(...) {
   dao.createOrUpdate(user);
}
```

and User has related data with Group by example:

```
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, foreign = true, foreignAutoCreate = true,
      foreignAutoRefresh = true)
private Group group;
```

When i have a repeated Group id value the operation fails:

```
lstUsers.get(0).getGroup().getId(); // group id = 1 <-- foreign insert
lstUsers.get(1).getGroup().getId(); // group id = 1 <-- crash
lstUsers.get(3).getGroup().getId(); // group id = 1 <-- crashed already
lstUsers.get(3).getGroup().getId(); // group id = 2 <-- crashed already
... etc.
```

i need to insert a group or groups that is not reppeated (insert only 1 time) automatically with foreignAutoCreate no manually.

```
lstUsers.get(0).getGroup().getId(); // group id = 1 <-- foreign insert
lstUsers.get(1).getGroup().getId(); // group id = 1 <-- foreign exists, skip
lstUsers.get(3).getGroup().getId(); // group id = 1 <-- foreign exists, skip
lstUsers.get(3).getGroup().getId(); // group id = 2 <-- foreign insert
```

there is a way to do this??

**UPDATE 1:**

Try with this test please:

```
public void poblatingUsersAndGroupsList(){
    List<User> lstUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    Group group1 = new Group();
    // this group doesn't exists in database
    group1.setId(1); // should be inserted by ForeignAutoCreate
    lstUsers.add(new User("user1",group1));
    lstUsers.add(new User("user2",group1));
    lstUsers.add(new User("user3",group1));

    Group group2 = new Group();
    group1.setId(2);
    // this group doesn't exists in database
    group1.setId(1); // should be inserted by ForeignAutoCreate
    lstUsers.add(new User("user4",group1));
    lstUsers.add(new User("user5",group2));
    lstUsers.add(new User("user6",group2));

    createUsersInGroup(lstUsers);
}

public void createUsers(List<User> lstUsers){
    for(User user : lstUsers){
        // here is the error
        // group1 inserted the 1st time 
        // the 2nd, 3rd, n times are throwing error
        // same for group2
        dao.createOrUpdate(user);
    }
}
```

foreignAutoCreate should work like this code, so we can avoid this block of code:

```
public void createUsers(List<User> lstUsers){
    for(User user : lstUsers){
        // (innecesary) calling or instantiating the groupDao 
        // (innecesary) check if not exists
        groupDao.createIfNotExists(user.getGroup());
        dao.createOrUpdate(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "crash" what you mean is throws an exception right?  Can you provide the exception you are getting?

Comment: E/SQLiteLog﹕ (2067) abort at 20 in [INSERT INTO `Group` (... etc,`id` ) VALUES (?,?,?)]:
    UNIQUE constraint failed: Group.id

Comment: This is an old question and I assume you moved on.  I was not able to reproduce this however and I've added tests to cover it.  See: https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/9f34c7371c580ba0d138176265490df904702fcf

Comment: i had to use manual check :/ but annotation should do it by us, i think that.

Comment: in your test you only make an insert of child with parent, the error occurs when you insert 2 or more childs (differents) with the same parent. like child1-parent1 (success), child2-parent2(success), child3-parent2(fail cus parent2 already exists)

Comment: that shouldn't stops the loop with an error, should check if parent already exists and skip it or update it.

Comment: That was the wrong check in.  I've also added a bunch more.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and I assume you moved on.  I was not able to reproduce this however.  I've expanded the test cases with multiple inserts using `dao.createOrUpdate(...)`.  See the [ForeignObjectTest unit test code](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/cb7fb131ae6317f10d07d8dcbfb94c355278efd8/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/dao/ForeignObjectTest.java).

One thing that I wonder about is that when you are creating a `User` with an assocaited `Group`, the `Group` must have been created already so that it has an `id`.  Is that possibly the problem?

```
Group group = new Group();
// need to do this first to have group get an id
groupDao.create(group);
User user = new User();
user.setGroup(group);
for(...) {
   dao.createOrUpdate(user);
}
```

Comment: maybe my bad, what's the meaning of "foreignAutoCreate = true" propperty annotation? my understand is Create Foreign automatically, but if having another meaning please tell me, i'm not expert. but i thought foreigntAutoCreate could or should handle creation of foreign and check if exists to update it or skip creation. in order to skip  **need to do this first to have group get an id** and get a cleanner code, just suggesting.

Comment: when foreignAutoCreate creates first "Group" in this case, it gets the inserted id of "Group", so next foreignAutoCreate should check the linked "Group" foreign field, and do something, idk, skip or update "Group", with different User.

Comment: i have edited my question, adding a test case more clear.

Comment: I can't get it to fail.  Something may have been fixed already in trunk @Kuriel.  In the future, a full junit test would be great.